# unloggable machine after login trashed by sudo startx

Tags: boot, login

I have read previous posts on this topic. sudo startx seems a very bad idea. The problem is that I now have no way to login to a terminal or gui session. The suggested solutions to the problem seem to suggest the manipulation of user files which are now secured (blocked off from access). I seem to have blocked ssh or never initiated it. I cannot recall ever having a "root" password.  Is there any solution for this scenario. (thanks)

Comment: I've looked for "forgotten passwords" which is a similar problem. Many requests for help are simply marked as "duplicate" with no link to a solution.  I'd be very happy to be redirected to a discussion on dealing with an unloggable machine.

Comment: I have tried google summary "From the official Ubuntu LostPassword documentation:", but can't get GRUB menu by holding shift down during reboot.

Comment: You can always use a live USB to boot, then mount your installation and `chown` back your (and only  your) files.

Comment: my USB boot defaults to user "ubuntu@ubuntu". Can I gain root privileges with such a session ?

Comment: The default `ubuntu` user in a live session has complete `sudo` privileges by default.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, mount lists a device: /dev/loop0

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, mount command gives a long list which includes "/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime) .... is that the device to mount. Once mounted will I be able to use "cd home" and then see my username as a directory. That will be exciting !

Comment: No, try using the `lsblk` command to see what partitions you have. By looking at the sizes you might be able to tell which partition to mount.

Comment: I think it may be sda1 with 95Gb. The live session seems to have mounted this in the media folder with the label "vs" which I believe was attached at install time. Permission denied to view this.  In media directory "ls" command does not see it, nor "vdir". Is there any way gain access to this mount point. (using mount fails with "already mounted ..message" ?? Certainly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your Ubuntu (or any other Linux) installation drive, sudo to `root` and then `chown` your files back.

Comment: the terminal login rejects my password

Answer (score 0):

The problem of "can't log in after sudo startx" has many duplications and various proposed remedies seemed to work for some cases; I will outline my conclusions since it took a while for me to find the solution that worked for me. 
BTW, if you enter a wrong password, the login dialogue tells you so. When the password is correct but the user files are mashed, the screen goes blank then silently returns to the login dialogue.

For me, the most crucial step was getting the grub options to come up during reboot. Left shift key (the most recommended option) would not work. Escape finally did work but was timing dependant. This is with Ubuntu 14.10. May be the older keyboard I use is a problem.
Once I could get to the root prompt:

- mount -o remount,rw /         [makes the file system writeable]
- cd /home                      [change to home directory]
- ls -l1                        [user directory must be owned by user]
- cd /home/myusername           [change to the user directory]
- ls -li .ICEauthority          [.ICEauthority file must be owned by user]
- ls -li .Xauthority            [.Xauthority file must be owned by user]

In my case the fault was with ownership of the .Xauthority file. It had become owned by root. I changed using chown.

- sudo chown myusername:myusername .Xauthority
- ls -li .Xauthority            [check to see the owner change worked]

finally reboot machine.